# HTML5 Drag and Drop issue with Cloning and replacing

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

Thanks for taking a look into my issue. I have been trying to figure this out for days at this point, reading every possible HTML5 Drag and Drop reference there is as well as reading through as much as I could here on stackflow and I just can't figure out.

So onto my problem:

Source: https://jsfiddle.net/dzsk7311/3/

```
<div id="divLeft">
  <div id="divLeft1">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designcontest/casino/96/Banana-icon.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="50" height="50">
  </div>
  <div id="divLeft2">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/rokey/smooth/128/apple-icon.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2" width="50" height="50">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="divRight">
  <div id="divRight1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div id="divRight2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div id="divRight3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div id="divRight4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</div>
```

-

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault();
   var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
   var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
   ev.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
   ev.stopPropagation();
   return false;
}
```

**What I want to accomplish:**

- Dragging images from `divLeft` to `divRight` (Which will actually be dragged to: `divRight1, divRight2, divRight3, divRight4`) through cloning to make sure the original image stays in place to be used again.
- Once image has been dropped to one of the four right div's, allow it to be a standalone image that can be dragged between the four div's independently without cloning and swapping places with the other image. So if I have an image in `rightDiv1` and in `rightDiv3`, and I drag the image in `rightDiv3` to `rightDiv1`, I want them to just swap places.
- If an image is being dropped from the `divLeft` to the 'divRight', replace an already existing image in the location with the new image.

**What the problem is:**

- Currently I have the cloning working with no issue, but if I drag a new image from the left to the right, it doesn't replace the image on the right.
- I also can't drag the images on the right among each other.

I hope this all makes sense, and I really appreciate any and all help since I have been racking my brain. I know that the code I have provided is limited, but I assure you, I have tried as many things as I possibly can think of and just wanted to go back to a good starting point for support.

Thank you all again.

Comment: Can you provide jfiddle or code snippet?

Comment: Hey Max, I did in the post above, can you not see them? Here is the jsfiddle though: Source: https://jsfiddle.net/dzsk7311/3/. Thanks so much for taking the time to look into this with me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have modified your function slighlty to update node id

```
function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  var isLeft = 'drag1' == data || "drag2" == data;
  var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
  nodeCopy.id = "img" + ev.target.id;
  if (!isLeft) {
    sourceNode = document.getElementById(data);
    sourceNode.parentNode.removeChild(sourceNode);
  }
  ev.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
  ev.stopPropagation();
  return false;
}
```

See [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dzsk7311/4/)

Comment: Max, thanks so much! This is very clever, I didn't even get close to this. I was using node.appendchild, and trying to actually append innerHTML. Part of my problem as well, that existed even before this fix. How can I get the apple to replace the banana(or banana replace the apple) when dropped from the left to the right? The functionality works perfect in the right div's. But I haven't been able to figure out how to replace what exists when dragging from the left to the right. That is the only question I have at this point. I can figure anything else that may remain out.

Comment: You just need to remove any node in the target container.

Comment: Done and done, thanks man! Enjoy the rest of your day. I don't have enough rep to up vote you, but once I do I will revisit this and do so.

Comment: You were very close, peace.